# Window's update error

Tags: windows-10, mac, macbook, boot-camp

I just recently, installed windows 10 in my mac using Bootcamp and after setting everything up and moving my attention to updating windows, it says  "Your device missing important security and quality updates". Also, there is some mention of download status and saying it's pending. Essentially, it's all too confusing for me like a mac user. Can someone help me out?

Here's an image of what the screen shows.

[image]

Comment: What precisely is your question & where is this purported error? Your machine is short of some updates. Some are downloading, some are waiting for the download to finish, then all will be installed & you'll be prompted to restart.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ye but I don't see any button for me to like "update" or press restart...nth. What exactly should I do after I see the screen, that is presented as an image above?

Comment: It hasn't finished yet. There is no error, just be patient. Windows does lots of updates, every week. You'll get used to just ignoring it until it forces you to restart, or restarts when you're not looking, which is even more annoying. Don't expect it to bahave like Mac, it doesn't, it's far more nannying & intrusive.

Comment: Should I then wait? 
Is it bad news, if I have already switched from windows to mac?? Should I go to windows now and just wait for all the updates to finish? But there isn't any like restart button or anything, Im hella confused.

Comment: Okay...I see. So, I'll just wait until it restarts.

Answer (score 1):

> I just recently, installed windows 10 in my mac using Bootcamp and after setting everything up and moving my attention to updating windows, it says "Your device missing important security and quality updates".

Your screenshot indicates your system is automatically downloading several updates.  `KB4551762` was released on March 12th 2020.  Since you installed Windows 10 version 1909 from an image released a year ago, it did not include any updates, released since September 2019.

> There is some mention of download status and saying it's pending. Essentially, it's all too confusing for me like a mac user.
>
> [image]

This is a normal status.  Any pending updates will automatically be installed after the other updates have been installed.

> Can someone help me out?

You need to be patient and wait until Windows displays a notification asking you to reboot your system.

Comment: +1 Perhaps, for people totally not used to this setup, add that you can just close the control panel & get on with your work - ignore it until it's finished. It will tell you if/when it needs you to restart, or restart itself overnight if the machine is left on.

Answer (score -1):

'**Your device is missing important security and quality fixes.**' essentially means that you've missed a lot of (important) updates and should update NOW.
'**Pending install**' means that other updates are being downloaded/installed, so that update isn't being installed. Wait a sec and it'll change to '**Installing - *XX*%**'

Comment: But what is this 'error'?

Comment: If you've enabled Fast Startup in Windows's Power management options, disable it, then reboot Windows and go back to Windows Update in Settings. Then you should be able to update Windows. You'll have to reboot again once all the updates have been installed. If that doesn't work, you may have to check in your GPOs if one or several rules prevent you from updating Windows on your own free will.

Comment: @Didier - that's misleading. It's not doing anything wrong that needs adjustment. It's simply not finished yet.

Comment: When it gets to this point, it usually means updates are frozen, for some reason. Restarting Windows without Fast Startup will usually clear the air. If not, then the OP should clear it himself, by emptying the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download folder content manually, after interrupting the wuauserv.svc. Sometimes, freezing/suspending the whole svchost.exe tree is necessary, because TIWorker.exe is stuck, and will prevent you from closing wuauserv.exe and its associated services.